# Is Parse providing 15 seconds for Cloud Code functions

Tags: parse-platform

I'm currently coding an app that utilizes Parse as a backend, but have run into a '124' error. I admit that I do a lot in my cloud functions, but, from what I've observed, it doesn't appear over 15 seconds. Could someone please confirm this? Below is the output.

> E2015-03-06T03:49:52.644Z] v286: Ran cloud function createEvent for
>   user puZNjFVfSm with:
>
> Input:
>   {"RSVPDate":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2015-03-06T04:49:52.000Z"},"description":"Sample event to showcase
>   functionality","group":{"max":5,"min":4},"max":50,"reoccur":{"day":1,"month":1,"stop":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2015-03-06T04:49:52.000Z"},"week":1},"title":"SampleFCFS"}
>
> Failed with: Execution timed out I2015-03-06T03:49:52.716Z] begin
>   I2015-03-06T03:49:52.717Z] creating Event - initial checks completed
>   I2015-03-06T03:49:52.718Z] Finished advanced checks
>   I2015-03-06T03:49:52.719Z] Event creation start
>   I2015-03-06T03:49:52.770Z] begin event creation
>   I2015-03-06T03:49:52.873Z] Finding role: company_employee_z0Zx39OyuY
>   I2015-03-06T03:49:52.875Z] Added and secured event
>   I2015-03-06T03:49:52.931Z] attaching role to 425Qy9v9e4
>   I2015-03-06T03:49:52.934Z] Adding participant

From what I can tell, it looks like I'm only getting 300Z (is that milliseconds?) on all my runs. Shouldn't I be getting 15 seconds?

Comment: I can't give a definitive answer. But I know some of my cold functions take at least 10 seconds (as I query external web services, which take up to 2 seconds to respond sometimes), I've never had problem there. That log message does imply it is timing out very quickly though. Are you sure the last operation you perform isn't timing?

Comment: If I were debugging this, I would start up a live console (by typing `parse develop <your app name>` so that I could view the log messages in real time, this may give you a better sense of what might be going on.

Comment: Do you call other functions before that? According to their docs one cloud code request has a max execution time of 15 seconds before hitting a timeout. This execution time is shared over multiple functions, so your first function could take up 14.7 seconds, which means your second function could timeout after being executed for .3 milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you all for responding so quickly. Currently, I'm calling the function through the following Php code:

'// Have one of the users create the event
$user = $users[0];
$user = ParseUser::login($user->username, "test");
$event = ParseCloud::run('createEvent', $params);'

This all occurs after my Php code deletes existing data in the current DB through queries and .destroy commands, so I don't think that would be taking away time. I'll try debugging with the CLI right now

Comment: Also, if I performed Parse.Promise.when queries, would that shorten my time? I don't call 10x functions, so the 300 miliseconds doesn't make sense still, but I could try removing them to gain a more accurate understanding of the time required for each component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I found that the issue was caused by using the addUnique function of Parse Objects with an array of pointers. By inserting ids instead of pointers, the issue was resolved.

Thank you for your help.